# Problem with documentclass memoir + pgfplots from data file

Tags: pgfplots, xetex, memoir, external-files

I'm using the documentclass `memoir` and I want to make a plot from a `file.dat` of two rows, nothing special. But I keep getting that `pgfplots` could not open the file. The point is that if I make a new document (`article`) the plot is generated without problem.

This is the code that works with `article` but not with `memoir`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} []
\addplot[] file{pdf.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Can somebody explain me what is happening?

Comment: Could you please provide a complete minimal working example?

Comment: It says `pdf.dat` but you mentioned `file.dat`. A typo maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this MWE (that you have not provided) and it seems work fine:

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = utf8

\begin{filecontents*}{pdf.dat}
0 1
1 2
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot file{pdf.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```